# Ubuntu 19.04 boots to blank screen

Tags: boot, screen, login-screen, 19.04

I turn off my laptop,  grub menu pops up,  I clicked on ubuntu and after some time it shows me blank screen.  I have set the login to automatically without any password required.

It showed the ubuntu logo and after some time it just appeared blank.  How can I fix this?  What might have gone wrong?  I want to know the reason behind and the solution.

Comment: Did you try booting into recovery mode, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode?